# Is it bad practice to have a relational table integer field as -ve (for some reason)

Tags: database, postgresql

Hi guys I have a question about database (postgresql specially).

I have 3 tables A, B and C 
C is a relational table of A and B (Like many to many relation)
Table C is as follows

```
----------------
| b_id  | a_id |
|-------|-------
|  1    | 2    |
|-------|-------
| -1    | 3    |
|--------------|
```

Now my Question is that can I put -ve value in C for the column b_id (for some reason obviously). is it good or bad.

Thanks.

Comment: @klin I can attest that +ve and -ve are mathematical slang, not sure if they're widely used/known though

Comment: `{b_id, a_id}` is a natural key for the `C` bridge table. Putting `-1 * b_id` in C.b_id  will violate a foreign key constraint `b_id = B.b_id`, if there exists such a constraint (which should exist IMO)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's just an convention nothing much. You can use negative numbers too. Database won't mind but those who use that database may seem it as a problem as it defies conventionality. But yes if needed you can do it.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing good or bad. It always depends on the requirement. If you require then you can do that but people who are going to use this must know about such convention as doing any comparison or any computation may lead into unexpected result due to -ve sign